# Explain the behavior of this re

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following:

```
>>> re.sub('(..)+?/story','\\g<1>','money/story')
'mey'
>>>
```

Why is capture group 1 the first letter and last two letters of `money` and not the first two letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first capture group does not contain `m` at all. What is being matched by `(..)+?/story` is `oney/story`.

The `(..)+?` matches an even number of characters, so the following is matched (spaced out to make it clearer):

```
m o n e y / s t o r y
  ^-^ ^-^
```

Then the replacement is the first capture group. Something you might not know is that when you have a repeated capture group (in this case `(..)+?`), then only the last captured group is kept.

To summarise, `oney/story` is matched, and replaced with `ey`, so the result is `mey`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the string `money` contains 5 letters (odd) not even, it won't even match the first letter `m`. `(..)+?` captures two characters and non-greedily repeats the pattern one or more times . Because the repetation quantifier `+` exists  next to the capturing group, it would capture tha last two characters of the match  . Now the captured group contains the last two characters of the match done by this `(..)+?` pattern. So you got `ey` as the captured string not the first `on`. So by replacing all the matched characters with the string inside the group index 1 `ey` will give you `mey`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/5)

Comment: Aren't the parentheses just representing capture grouping?  Do they have a bracketing function too?  Shouldn't the + repeat just the previous . and not ..?

Comment: yep, `+` repeat the previous token one or more times. Because the previous token is `(..)+`, first it matches all the two characters and captures only the last two not the first two chars ..